# Visual Studio Installer project not including all files for WinForms hosted Blazor

Tags: winforms, blazor, windows-installer

I have a Blazor app that I have hosted in a WinForms app using BlazorWebView. I am trying to create an .msi to install the app on a desktop using a Visual Studio Installer Project in VS2022.

If I publish the WinForms app directly to a folder using Publish... from VS or `dotnet publish` I get a folder with everything needed and it works great. However, if I install the app from the .msi created by the Installer project some files aren't included which make the app unusable. Notably, the `wwwroot` folder containing css and site assets isn't included, nor is the `WebView2Loader.dll` file.

This image shows the difference between the normal WinForms project publish output (left) and what the .msi installs (right):

[image]

Comment: For anyone else finding this issue. I had the same symptoms but with WPF instead of winforms and was able to fix the issue by including the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf" nuget package in the WPF project.